# Show div after a button becomes active

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, button

I have a div with the class name `ui-widget hidden` that is initially hidden on page load with:

```
.hidden {display: none}
```

I also have a button that is initially disabled, and when a certain file is uploaded, it becomes active with:

```
document.getElementById("button").disabled = false;
```

What I'd like to be able to do is use `.toggleClass()` or something else (maybe `.show()`?) to show the div once the button becomes active. However, everything I seem to find has to do with buttons being clicked.

Comment: Why not add `$('.ui-widget.hidden').removeClass('hidden')` after the line `document.getElementById("button").disabled = false;`

Comment: Hm. I could have sworn I tried that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove hidden class after button active.

```
document.getElementById("button").disabled = false; 
document.getElementById("divid").classList.remove("hidden");
```